# Frame-time/frame-rate logging software

Tags: windows, 3d, performance-analysis

Needs:

- log frame-rates of videogames to some text format
- not impede performance too much
- keep exact sub-millisecond timings
- Support Windows
- no need to configure manually before each session, "set and forget"

Wants:

- CSV/text output

Comment: One slight problem is that IIRC Windows does not provide a sub-millisecond timer or access to any that the hardware possesses such. However, what is the point of logging frame rates below your display frame rate? Most current displays are 50-75 FPS = 20-13 msec/frame and even 200 FPS = 5 msec/frame. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate

Comment: I want to log the exact timing between each frames to measure frame/microstuttering. My hope is to quantitatively analyze a certain performance upgrade in real-world scenarios.

Comment: I think that you are going to need hardware timing to get the resolution you need, some specific graphics high end graphics cards may provide the information that you need but it is likely to be card specific.